# PHP Laravel 5.2: Eloquent relationship for subscriptions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I think I got a little stuck and I just need someone to clarify things. So what I got is a user system which includes subscriptions for people to "subscribe" to their content (as you already know it from FB, Twitter, YT etc).

My database model looks like this:

```
Users
id
username

Subsccriptions
id
user_id
sub_id
```

Currently I have one model for Users and one Model for Subscriptions. The model from the user:

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

In comparison, my subscription object:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

So in my personal opinion this is a 1:many relationship. If I call the user object with User->subscriptions()->get() I can get the subscription and it's sub id, so I know who THE CURRENT user has subscribed.

People told me the opposite and it's supposed to be a many-to-many relationship. Did I do something wrong? Can I automatically convert the sub_id into a user through relationships in Eloquent?

// EDIT:
Here is the current code to receive my subscribers for a user

```
public function index()
{
    $subs = Auth::user()->subscriptions()->get()->all();

    $submodels = [];
    foreach($subs as $sub) {
        array_push($submodels,User::find($sub->sub_id));
    }

    return view('home', [
        'subscriptions' => $submodels
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey Brett, thanks for your fast answer. I'm not sure if I missunderstood your way to fix it or you missunderstood the question so I'd like to clarify:

Currently I got 2 user id's in there. One for my user, and one for the other user. If I'd remove the user_id key, I coudln't access it from the users object of my current user of choice. So instead I do use this code to get the subscriptions accounts up and running. Is this right?

I've edited the code at the bottom to show you the code to retrieve the current subscription id's for my view!

Comment: As other people suggested, your relation should be many to many. In fact the table you have for subscriptions is used for the pivot table. You need another table where you can save the subscription information (whatever the content you are referring). Change the "role" word with "subscription" in this documentation and that's what you are looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many . Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey Can, thanks for your answer. But why exactly should it be many to many if it seems to be right like this? I'm sorry if it sounds crazy, but for some reason I won't understand the WHY :/

Comment: You mentioned in your question "a user system which includes subscriptions for people to "subscribe" to their content". What exactly do you mean by their content? If these contents are shared by different users, you don't want to create a database record for each user with the same subscription content. Instead you create one subscription that many user can share.

Comment: With your current relationships 1 user can have many subscriptions, but a  subscription can only belong to a single user. If that is your expected behaviour then your current set up is fine. Your current set up is identical to the Post > Comments example in the laravel documentation.